# Как обработать все файлы определенного расширения в директории? Python

Tags: python, файлы, файловая-система

В задании требуется считать содержимое всех файлов расширения `.csv` в директории которая задается пользователем.
Как это реализовать?

Comment: А как пробовали?

Comment: Я не знаю как это реализовать, поэтому и задал этот вопрос.

Comment: Что не получается, считать содержимое csv или получить пути всех файлов с расширением csv?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для получения путей к файлам существуют 2 самых распространенных варианта:

1. С использованием функции [walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) модуля `os`. В данном случае происходит опрос и вложенных директорий. Вариант использования:

`files_list = [os.path.join(root, fname) for root, sub, files in os.walk(r"c:\in") for fname in files]`

2. Использование функции [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#module-glob) модуля `glob` Данная функция часто используется в задач анализа данных и ML.

`from glob import glob files_lst = glob(fr"c:\*.csv")`

p.s Что то мне подсказывает, что Вам надо считать несколько csv и объединить их в один df - если это так, тогда вам [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe)

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете воспользоваться модулем `glob` и его одноимённым методом для поиска файлов по некоторой маске.

***Пример:***

```py
import glob


for file in glob.glob('*.csv'):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

#просто найти файлы.csv
for f in os.scandir('Ваш_путь_к_директории'):
    if f.is_file() and f.path.split('.')[-1].lower() == 'csv':
        print(f.path)

#прочитать содержимое
for f in os.scandir('Ваш_путь_к_директории'):
    if f.is_file() and f.path.split('.')[-1].lower() == 'csv':
        with open(f.path, 'r') as csvfile:
            print(csvfile.read())
```